Refactoring a Spring MVC application using Spring Cloud API Gate
I recently began breaking a monolithic Java Spring Application which uses MVC and JSPs up into smaller microservices. I've been using Spring Cloud API Gateway thus far. I've continued serving JSPs to the client side using the API Gateway. What I want to know is if there are any draw backs to doing this?
Many of the tutorials I've seen have used the API Gateway to split up an API without a view layer. Instead, a separate client side was creating using a popular library like React to handle requests to the API Gateway. So, I'm not sure if sending JSP across an API Gateway is considered a bad practice or if there are problems this could create later on.
I successfully got a Spring MVC application to serve JSP to the desired URL using Spring Cloud.
My question is this. Is sending JSP across an API Gateway considered a bad practice in software development. If so, why?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

API Gateway by definition means it sits behind a front-end client to access the backend API. So, no. Sending a JSP is not a practice.
